# Any way to enable Float and Int in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In my code I never use anything other than `Int32` or `Float64`.

Yet `Int` and `Float` are not working in Crystal and I always have to type 32 and 64 at the end which is annoying.

Is there any hacky way to enable usage of Float and Int?

Comment: I don't think that's something to bother about at all. `Float64` and `Int32` are already pretty short type names and I don't see any benefit in making it even shorter which obviously loses expressiveness.

Comment: @JohannesMüller It adds noise to the code. The key feature of ruby is clean, readable and compact syntax. It's hard to justify adding `32` and `64` noise when it doesn't have any meaning (in my case, as I use it in 99% cases) and could be just avoided.

Comment: Maybe you could be interested in https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8111 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [type aliases](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/alias.html), e.g., `alias Int = Int32`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea because `::Int` is also a global constant and reading `Int` when you mean `Int32` might be confusing.